# Send to Mailman list via Drupal Webform accepts all messages because site owner is on list

Tags: email, drupal, drupal-7, cpanel, mailman

I have a mailing list set up in Mailman (on my webserver via Cpanel). I am also running a Drupal site, on the same domain as my mailing list addresses, which includes a webform that can post a message to the mailing list.

The webform requires an email address, and this email address is used as the "from" address for the message to the mailing list. My Mailman configuration rejects all messages from non-subscribers.

The problem: all messages sent from this webform are accepted, whether or not the email address entered is on the list.

After much testing, I've discovered that this only happens because my own email address is a member of the list. If I remove my email address, then the correct and expected results happen - member emails are sent, and non-member emails are rejected.

I believe that this must be happening because my email address is the site owner address in Drupal's configuration - seems like somehow Mailman is processing this before it processes the submitter's email, and deems it valid.

I do need my own email address to be a member of this list. Has anyone encountered this before? Any solutions known?

Many thanks!

Comment: Have you checked the email headers to see what is being set by Drupal? Likely you have headers for both the sender and the site email address. Also for non-programing related Drupal questions you'll probably do better at http://drupal.stackexchange.com/.  If you have custom code you've written you should mention it and include some examples in your question.

Comment: Thanks for the advice - I'm not sure whether it's a Drupal problem or a Mailman problem, to be honest.

I checked the headers, and I can't find the site email address in any of the messages (both before and after the site email was unsubscribed).